# минуты в массиве сконвертировать в часы

Tags: javascript

Задача в том чтобы сконвертировать числа из минут в часы для дальнейшей фильтрации по ним.

```
let monday = [
  ['Write a tutorial',180],
  ['Some web development',120]
];
let tuesday = [
  ['Keep writing that tutorial',240],
  ['Some more web development',180],
  ['A whole lot of nothing',240]
];

let tasks = [monday,tuesday];
```

Comment: Разделить на 60 ?

Comment: Разделить это понятно. вопрос как добраться до этих элементов чтобы их изменить.

Comment: А как вы будете "фильтровать по ним", если не можете до них добраться?

Comment: Это уже совсем другая история)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let monday = [
  ['Write a tutorial',180],
  ['Some web development',120]
];
let tuesday = [
  ['Keep writing that tutorial',240],
  ['Some more web development',180],
  ['A whole lot of nothing',240]
];

let tasks = [monday,tuesday];

let converted = tasks.map( arr => {
  return arr.map( arr => {
    return [ arr[0], Math.ceil(arr[1]/60) ]
  })
});

console.log(converted);
```